# Reusing routes in another project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, castle-windsor

I have standart MVC web project that register routes in global.asax. My MVC project includes `ContentService`, that use different conversions from special syntax to html, including converting special formatted text to internal links. It have method `Render(Urlhelper url, string text)`. I use `WindsorInstaller` to register ContentService that has no dependencies.

I have another project with my services, and I want to place ContentService here to reuse in another web project. If I place it in services project, Render method should get UrlHelper by any way. I tryed to register UrlHelper in my windsor installer, but it's ctor depends on RequestContext and I don't know want to do next.

By absolute goal is to reuse routing of my main web project in another web project when generating content url. It is possible to use areas to organize different projects, and it allow me don't place ContentService to services project, but this solution does not suit me, because I need to place this sites on different server machines.

Your solutions? (using Windsor Container / creating special component that installs routes / something other?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always implement dynamic routing , ie, get your routes from a database or xml file.

Look at this post for a simple solution :
[Dynamic Routing](http://jcreamerlive.com/2011/01/19/dynamic-routes-in-asp-net-mvc-3/)